# Unpivot 3 set of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these rows wish to convert them into columns in TABLE Company

| ID | EmpID | DepartmentA | DepartmentB | DepartmentC | Email1 | Email2 | Email3 | Phone1 | Phone2 | Phone3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2343 | Y | Y |  | 2343@YAHOO.COM |  |  | 562-5845484 | 714-5885554 |  |
| 2 | 5454 |  |  | Y | 5454@HOTMAIL.COM | 5454@YAHOO.COM | 714-5848788 |  |  |  |

I want to get a result table that looks like this:

| ID | EmpID | Department | DepartmentType | Email | EmailType | Phone | PhoneType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2343 | y | DepartmentA | 2343@YAHOO.COM | Email1 | 562-5845484 | Phone1 |
| 2 | 2343 | y | DepartmentB |  |  | 714-5885554 | Phone2 |
| 3 | 5454 | y | DepartmentC | 5454@HOTMAIL.COM | Email1 | 714-5848788 | Phone1 |
| 4 | 5454 |  |  | 5454@YAHOO.COM | Email2 |  |  |

Basically, I wanted to have 3 unpivot in an select statement.

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    EmpID,
    Department,
    DepartmentType,
    Email,
    EmailType,
    Phone,
    PhoneType
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Id, EmpID, 
         DepartmentA, DepartmentB, DepartmentC,  
         Email1, Email2, Email3,
         Phone1, Phone2, Phone3
     FROM 
         Company) src

UNPIVOT
(
   Department FOR DepartmentType IN (DepartmentA,DepartmentB,DepartmentC )
) pvt1

UNPIVOT
(
Email  For EmailType IN (Email1, Email2,Email3 )
) pvt2
UNPIVOT
(
Phone For PhoneType IN (Phone1,Phone2,Phone3)
) pvt3

WHERE RIGHT(Department ,1) = RIGHT(Email  ,1)
      RIGHT(Department ,1) = RIGHT(Phone  ,1)
```

Some how I got same value occurring many times. Is this a correct way?

Thanks,

Hung

Comment: Which dbms are you using? UNPIVOT is a product specific functionality.

Comment: I am using MSSQL server.